# WebKit.NET - use IE cookies for all requests

Tags: .net, webkit, webkit.net

I have a site that is logged into Internet Explorer already, so when I open it up I don't need to log into it again. I want that URL to be opened in WebKit Browser insdie my C# application that should show the same logged in page. How is it possible?

This seems to be linked to using IE Cookies, is there any way?

WebKit library: http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Many websites use session cookies for login information, which should not be persisted in the cookie storage. This cookie will be in browser's memory and there is no easy way to convince browser to share it's cookies.

If the site is using persistent cookies, you can try following workarounds.

You can export cookies from IE and then translate the cookies in the format webkit needs and import it. OR

You can set cookie storage for webkit, login to site once and use the same storage every time.

Cross browser cookie sharing is difficult to achieve as each browser manages cookies in its own way.

Comment: Regarding your comment on difficulty to achieve all this, it seems exactly true as per my research uptil now. However, I was able to get cookies from IE using Windows API, but I think they were all missing the session coookies that are actually required to keep up the actual session with the server. But I don't know if it is still possible to get session cookies too from IE.